# Login validation not happening using ajax and json

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When i log in, it has to first check if the entered username and password matches the data present in the json file. 
This is not happening. It logs in at every enetered username and password. Please let me know where i have gone wrong.

This is the index.html

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>

                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Screen1.css">
                <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type = "text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.8/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
            <!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Validation.js"></script>
             -->    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/AccountAuthentication.js"></script>


            enter code here
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

            </head>


            <body>
                <div data-role="page" id="">
                    <div data-role="header" class="ui-bar-a ui-page-theme-a ui-bar-inherit">
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

                    <form id="UserLogin" class="ui-body ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false" method="get" action="HomePage.html"> 
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Email address" id="uname" value=""/>
                        </div>  
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log In"/>

                        <!-- <a href="HomePage.html" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow" id="submit" data-ajax="false">Submit</a> -->
                        <a href="Register.html" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow ">Register</a>
                    </form> 
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar-a ui-page-theme-a ui-bar-inherit" data-position="fixed">
                        <h6>2016</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </body>

            </html>

    AccountAuthentication.js

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#submit").click(function(){

        var uname = $('#uname').val();  
        var password = $('#password').val();
        console.log("this is from form: "+uname);
        console.log("this is from form: "+password);
        alert(uname);
                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    url:"json/validate.json", 
                    success: function(data) {   
                        alert("inside success");
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        console.log(value.uname);
                            if (value.uname != '' && value.password!='')
                                {
                                    if(value.uname!=uname && value.password!=password)
                                    alert("password correct");
                                    return false;
                                }
                        });


                    },
                    error: function() {

                    }
               });


    });

    });

    validation.js

     {
            "uname": "pooja",
            "password": "1234"

        }
```

Comment: check in case Comparing with `case sensitive` condition.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to "return false" from ajax success function, as ajax is asynchronous you will not receive false.

Instead of returning value from ajax success function call some function from it and write your desired code(Wether to login user or not) in that function.

Answer (score 0):

So when you make an ajax call, the response is asyncronous so your submit function runns, but it will not wait for the data to come back. Though i wouldn't validate a user that way, if you want to follow that path you can set you ajax request to be syncronous. and decide once the data comes back.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#submit").click(function(){

            var uname = $('#uname').val();  
            var password = $('#password').val();
            console.log("this is from form: "+uname);
            console.log("this is from form: "+password);

              var p = false;
              $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"text",
                url:"https://httpbin.org/get", 
                async : false, //This does what you want, 
                success: function(data) {   
                 //Your if condition
                 p = true; //will submit the form
                 p = false; //will avoid submitting the form


                },
                error: function() {

                }
              });

              return p; //Returns according to the validation




        });

        });
```

Here is a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/zA0ykahcaPbWT92n2Csu?p=preview

notice that if you set p to tru you form will submit. if you set it to false it wont.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

> $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("#submit").click(function(){

    var uname = $('#uname').val();  
    var password = $('#password').val();
    console.log("this is from form: "+uname);
    console.log("this is from form: "+password);
    var obj=new Object();
    obj.uname = uname ;
    obj.password=password;

    alert(uname);
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
                data:obj,
                url:"json/validate.json", 
                success: function(data) {   
                    alert("inside success");
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    console.log(value.uname);
                        if (value.uname != '' && value.password!='')
                            {
                                if(value.uname!=uname && value.password!=password)
                                alert("password correct");
                                return false;
                            }
                    });


                },
                error: function() {

                }
           });


});

});
```

Comment: Tried it. Not happening.